# undefined method `httpdate' for "...":String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

This code suddenly stopped working and I don't understand why.

```
class MyClass < ApplicationController
  ...
  def method
    @myobject = @my_objects.order(:updated_at).last
    if stale?(@myobject)
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

The problem is in **if stale?(@myobject)** and error is

NoMethodError in MyClass#my_method

undefined method `httpdate' for "2016-10-23 20:44:26 UTC":String

actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/http/cache.rb:64:in `last_modified='

---

The problem were solved by replacing the code:

```
class MyClass < ApplicationController
  ...
  def my_method
    @myobject = @my_objects.order(:updated_at).last
    t = Time.parse(@myobject.updated_at)
    if stale?(etag: @myobject, last_modified: t)
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

But first version should work too by [API doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/ConditionalGet.html#method-i-stale-3F) and it worked!

I'd like to understand causes made first version unworkable and fix the problem. All I have changed recently - Debian packages upgrade, but I don't think this was a cause.

---

OS: Debian GNU/Linux 8.6 (jessie)

Ruby version: ruby-2.3.0 [ x86_64] (rvm)

Rails version: 5.0.0.1

Answer (score 0):

This may be because of the Date-time field. Whenever you use this you need to parse Time.parse for time or  Date.parse for date. Time zone is also one main problem.

Please refer rails Doc for that.